# setting checkbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
$('#chkBox').click(function() {
    $('#hiddenBox').val($('input').is(':checked'));
});
```

I want it to be where if i click on the checkbox, in my hidden field, I set the value to true else if it's not clicked, the value would be false. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#chkBox').click(function() {
    // I prefer assigning a string
    $('#hiddenBox').val(this.checked ? 'true' : 'false');

    // but in actual fact, this should be enough
    $('#hiddenBox').val(this.checked);
}).triggerHandler('click');​​​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pGkGz/1/

And see http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/

Comment: @ karim79 -- this will give me true if i check the checkbox but i want it where if it's not checked, i would get false, more like false on page load until i click the checkbox.

Comment: @hersh - Updated. You need to trigger the click handler on page load, using `.triggerHandler`.